# Trouble clearing object from array using buttons (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to move an image and data-id attribute from one section of divs, to a placeholder section of divs. I also want to be able to splice out those objects from the array when clicking the 'remove' button from either section.

It's mostly working by targeting the 'data-id' attribute and then performing the actions I want it to - but I'm running into one bug.

https://jsfiddle.net/kgmucdac/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var selections = [];
  var prodLength = 4;
  var arrayVal = "";

  $(".killThis").click(function() {
    killCount();
  });

  $("#products").on('click', '.add', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('add');
    $(this).addClass('removeTop');
    $(this).text("remove");
    $('.remove').show();
    arrayVal = ($(this).data('id'));   
    if (selections.length <= prodLength) {
      selections.push({src: $(this).parent().find('img').attr('src'),vid: $(this).data('id')});
    }
    addProd();
    console.table(selections);
  });

  $("#products").on('click', '.removeTop', function () {
    arrayVal = ($(this).data('id'));
    $(this).removeClass('removeTop');
    $(this).addClass('add');
    $(this).text("add");
    nukeProd();
    cleanArray();
    drawProds();
  });

  $('#placeholders').on('click', '.remove', function () {
    arrayVal = ($(this).data('id'));
    console.log(arrayVal);
    nukeProdReverse();
    cleanArray();
    tempClear();
    drawProds();
  })

  function drawProds() {
    var prods = $('#placeholders').find('.placeholder');
    for (var i = 0; i < prods.length; i++) {
      var prod = prods[i];
      var selection = selections[i];
      if ((selection != undefined)) {
        $(prod).find('img').attr('src', selection.src);
        $(prod).find('.remove').attr('data-id', selection.vid)
      } else {
        $(prod).find('img').attr({
          'src': 'https://i.imgur.com/D6MQP01.png'
        });
        $(prod).find('.remove').css('display', 'none');
      }
    }
  }

  function addProd() {
    drawProds();
  }

  function nukeProd() {
    $('.placeholder[data-id="' + arrayVal + '"]').find('img').attr({
      'src': 'https://i.imgur.com/D6MQP01.png'
    });
    $('.remove[data-id="' + arrayVal + '"]').attr('data-id', '');    
  }

  function cleanArray() {
    for(var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
      if(selections[i].vid == arrayVal) {
        selections.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }    
    }
    console.table(selections);
  }  

  function nukeProdReverse() {
    $('.placeholder[data-id="' + arrayVal + '"]').find('img').attr({
      'src': 'https://i.imgur.com/D6MQP01.png'
    });
    $('.remove[data-id="' + arrayVal + '"]').removeAttr('data-id');
    $('.removeTop[data-id="' + arrayVal + '"]').text("add");
    $('.removeTop[data-id="' + arrayVal + '"]').addClass('add');
    $('.removeTop[data-id="' + arrayVal + '"]').removeClass('removeTop');        
  }

  function tempClear() {
  $('.remove').removeAttr('data-id');
  }

  function killCount() {
    console.log(arrayVal);
  }

});
```

That's my JSFiddle that I've been working on. When I add the products in any order from the top row, I can delete them using the top row's remove buttons, no issues.

However, using the bottom row's 'remove' buttons, I can only remove them all if I start from right to left (4th, 3rd, 2nd, 1st)... If I remove them in any other order, e.g., the 3rd, the one that slides into its place will not work correctly.

I think it has something to do with the index incrementation but I'm kind of at the end of my road on this in terms of what I know how to do/cobble together.